# Is there a way to select only the first item each min in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with entries like such

```
Time                     Value
2020-04-24 9:12:02       $2.50
2020-04-24 9:12:31       $2.52
2020-04-24 9:13:12       $2.56
2020-04-24 9:13:48       $2.51
2020-04-24 9:14:08       $2.51
```

Ideally, I would like to pull only the first entry made each minute so I get a table like this.

```
Time                     Value
2020-04-24 9:12:01       $2.50
2020-04-24 9:13:12       $2.56
2020-04-24 9:14:08       $2.51
```

Is there a way to do this. Time is formatted as a datetime

Thanks

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by date_format(time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') order by time) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

This formats the time as a string, up to the minute.  It then returns the first value for each minute.

Comment: What's about:   SELECT substr(Time,1,15) as Time_Column , Value FROM Your_Table
GROUP by Time_Column;

Comment: @AziMez . . . If the column is stored as a `datetime`, use date/time functions, not string functions.

Answer (score 0):

> Just try it; **tested** in `SQLite`. For `SQL Server` use: `SUBSTRING` instead `Substr` function.

```
SELECT substr(Time,1,15) as Time_Column , Value FROM Your_Table
GROUP by Time_Column;
```